# Javascript how can i pass an int by reference

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

Is it possible to pass an int by reference in Javascript?

```
function myFunction(myval) {
    myval = 3 
}

a = Number(5)
myFunction(a)
console.log(a) //gives 5
```

How can I get 3, instead of 5?

I found a solution myself like this

```
function myFunction(myval) {
    myval.val = 3
}

a = { val: 5 }
myFunction(a)
console.log(a.val)
```

see frederik's comment below which clears my confusion about Number.

Comment: No you cannot pass any primitive value by reference

Comment: You're not even calling `myFunction`

Comment: how about objects?

Comment: @DenisSmith yes with object you can achieve what you're trying to achieve

Comment: actually I am getting undefined, not 5

Comment: because myFunction returns undefined

Comment: I see, I converted to a Number, still I get 5

Comment: The `Number()` function parses an object into a number, it does not return an object containing a number.

Comment: ah frederik thanks a lot, now it makes sense, i thought it was creating an object containing a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why it gives `undefined`

Because there is no explicit return from `myFunction` so it implicitly returns `undefined` which is being printed in console

```js
function myFunction(myval) {
    myval = 3
}

a = 5
console.log(myFunction(a))
```

---

**In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the new operator), Number can be used to perform a type conversion.**

```js
let a = Number(5)
console.log(typeof a)
```

---

You can do something like this

```js
function myFunction(myval) {
  myval.a = 3
}

let obj = {
   a : 5
}

myFunction(obj)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I updated my code, is that wrong? I called the myFunction, then check a to see that it did not change even though it is an object now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a number by reference.
Here example with object:

```js
function incrementTheCounter(obj) {
    obj.counter++;
}

const a = {counter: 5};
incrementTheCounter(a);

console.log(a.counter);
```